# Solving coupled 2nd-order differential equation

Tags: nonlinear-equations, differential-equations, numerical-integration

I would appreciate it if you could help me solve the following coupled equation numerically
$$
[-\frac{1}{2} \partial_r^2 + v_0(r) -E]\psi_{\ell} + v_1(r) \psi_{1-\ell}(r) = 0,
$$
where $\ell = 0 , 1$ with initial conditions
$$
\partial_r \psi_0(0) = 0,\\
\psi_1(0) = 0.
$$
I do not know how to determine the initial start.

Comment: Welcome to SciComp.SE. I think that you are missing another equation for $\psi_1$ or $\psi_0$.

Comment: Thank you :). This is a 2 coupled equations for $\ell =0 $ and for $\ell=1$

Comment: What is the domain? What are $v_0$, $v_1$, and $E$? Since this is a second order problem, you are missing one initial or boundary condition for each equation. This determines whether this is an IVP or BVP, which determines suitable discretization schemes.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @cos_theta. $v_0$ and $v_1$ are some functions of $r$, and $E$ is a parameter and it is positive $E>0$.

Comment: @Ghoti, what are the missing initial or boundary conditions for each equation? It is a second order equation, so you need two conditions for each equation in order to get a unique solution. Also, what is the domain?